# how many threads a traffic signal application need?

Tags: java, multithreading

How many threads in minimum will be required for developing a traffic signal application?
I think it is only one, because when any one of the lights is in green the other 3 directions will be red. And for this application there is no need for multiple operations to be run parallel y.

Comment: this was asked in interview

Comment: By considering same time duration in all the directions..in a sequential manner can wait and notify methods be used to perform this operation by using one thread ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a driver, I sure hope it's only one thread!

You would only need one thread, but imagine the implications of non-threadsafe code or threading bugs...
**someone could literally die!**

#### Edited

Actually, "it depends" is the correct answer, if there is one.

Simple traffic lights, for example pedestrian crossings, could simply block waiting for a button press then complete the cycle and return to a blocking wait again.

Complex event-driven lights that can receive many inputs, may need multiple threads if the hardware doesn't support interrupts or other single threaded mechanisms for dealing with real time input signals.

Comment: Not really. You'd need at least one more thread for listening to events. For instance, a fire truck might signal all traffic lights in the next 3 blocks to go red.

Answer (score 2):

This question cannot be answered meaningfully without knowing what the scope of entire application is.  (In the simple case, a traffic light *simulation* could certainly be implemented in a single thread ... if the conditions were right.)

However, *real world* control systems for things like traffic lights are typically written in languages like C that are better at interfacing with controller hardware.  That makes your question moot ... kind of.

Comment: +1 IMHO This is the correct answer (my answer was rather a lighthearted one)

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, this is an useless exercise without knowing the exact conditions and constraints you have.

But here's my shot: I would probably have 4 threads:

- Main thread -- manages the lifecycle
- Receiver thread -- receives events from other sources, probably from different hardware parts, like the fire truck "remote control", or communication from the nearby traffic lights to determine if they the nearby traffic lights are in sync.
- Broadcaster thread -- dispatches signals from this specific traffic light to other consumers (other traffic lights, command and control center, ...)
- Processing thread -- gets delegated the processing of the events sent and received from the other two threads (Receiver, Broadcaster).

Answer (score 0):

In a very trivial case yes. But usually traffic signal depends on so many factors like :

1. Time for which it will be red/green based on traffic
2. On any intersection points of 2-3 roads signals of each road should be in sync.

an so on...

So there is no fixed answer to this.